# How to use handlers to output different texts based on number of button clicks in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, handlers, actionevent

I'm trying to use Handlers to achieve some task based upon button clicks. For example, if the button is pressed once, it must output 1 or if the button is pressed twice, it must output 2.
This must be done within 5 seconds. I've done this in android. But I get some errors while doing it in java. This is the equivalent android code. I want to implement the same in java using Handlers only.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (dblBckToExitPrssdOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.dblBckToExitPrssdOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            dblBckToExitPrssdOnce=false;                       
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Just use a flag `isFirstClick`. If it is, start a timer. If the timer goes of before the second, do something, like disable the button. If the button is pressed in time, stop the timer. I'm interested in seeing how _you_ tried to implement this, and where you are getting errors. Please post what you have tried. And use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a flag `isFirstClick`. If it is (the first click), start a timer (`javax.swing.Timer`). If the timer goes off before the second click, do something, like disable the button. If the button is pressed in time, stop the timer. For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimedButtonClickDemo {

    private JButton button = null;

    public TimedButtonClickDemo() {
        button = getTimedButton();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JButton getTimedButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Press Me");
        button.addActionListener(new TimerButtonListener());
        return button;
    }

    private class TimerButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        private Timer timer = null;
        private boolean isFirstClick = true;

        public TimerButtonListener() {
            timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    System.out.println("Too slow, Jack! Better eat your Wheaties!");
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (isFirstClick) {
                button.setText("Press Again");
                timer.start();
                isFirstClick = false;
            } else {
                timer.stop();
                button.setText(" Press Me ");
                isFirstClick = true;
                System.out.println("You did it. Must be on that Red Bull");
            }   
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TimedButtonClickDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

See more about how to use timers at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: I tried inserting texts into JTextFields based on this concept and it works. But what should I do to add the next word to the JTextField on the same basis? Like there's already Press Me in the JTextField. What is the logic to get the text in the JTextField as "Press MePress Me" ?